# Drupal 7 fetch equivalent

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

https://www.codeenigma.com/community/blog/drupal-7-cheat-sheet-database
https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7

I cannot wrap my head around the changes from Drupal 6 -> 7.

```
"SELECT CRS_sales.User, CRS_Goals.*, 
sum(CRS_sales.CompUnits) as CompUnits, 
sum(CRS_sales.KBUnits) as KBUnits, 
sum(CRS_sales.PrinterUnits) as PrinterUnits, 
sum(CRS_sales.MouseUnits) as MouseUnits, 
Count(CRS_sales.Comp) as CompCount
sum(CRS_sales.CompUnits + CRS_sales.KBUnits + CRS_sales.PrinterUnits + CRS_sales.MouseUnits) as UnitsTotal,
FROM CRS_sales 
INNER JOIN CRS_Goals
ON CRS_sales.User=CRS_Goals.User
WHERE date(CRS_sales.Created) = "01/10/2015" GROUP BY CRS_sales.User
order by UnitsTotal DESC";
```

How do I fetch this information for as many rows exist?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Drupal provide db_query($query) method. you can simply pass your query in this. Although this method is also exist in drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this SQL to db_query() function to get the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use db_query function e.g.

```
$result = db_query("your sql here");
$data = $result->fetchAll();
```

If your query uses user data you should sanitize it through Drupal's placeholders 
https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code